# Change indescriptive axis names of Pandas Panel and Panel4D

Tags: python, pandas, panel

The standard axis names of a Panel are Items, Major_axis and Minor_axis

```
In [2]: pd.Panel()
Out[2]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 0 (items) x 0 (major_axis) x 0 (minor_axis)
Items axis: None
Major_axis axis: None
Minor_axis axis: None
```

That is indescriptive as hell, and it gets worse for Panel4D, where Labels is added as fourth axis. Is there a way to change them during initialization? Or can I use `pd.core.create_nd_panel_factory` to create a new Panel4D factory with different axis names?

EDIT: 
So what I finally would like to have is

```
Out[3]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 0 (items) x 0 (major_axis) x 0 (minor_axis)
X axis: None
Y axis: None
Z axis: None
```

Comment: when you create a Panel on the contrary it is very descriptive. You would like to add something like: `Item axis -  Here are the name of the different DataFrames: None` ? Sorry but what you try to achieve is not explicit.

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel: Sorry, I do not get your point.

Comment: that was my point ... editing the label or adding something ... but good to have added the output!

Comment: checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533093/pandas-access-axis-by-user-defined-name

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer given in [pandas access axis by user-defined name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533093/pandas-access-axis-by-user-defined-name) is for an old pandas version and does not provide full functionality, this is how it works:

```
from pandas.core.panelnd import create_nd_panel_factory
from pandas.core.panel import Panel

Panel4D = create_nd_panel_factory(
    klass_name='Panel4D',
    orders=['axis1', 'axis2', 'axis3', 'axis4'],
    slices={'labels': 'labels',
            'axis2': 'items',
            'axis3': 'major_axis',
            'axis4': 'minor_axis'},
    slicer=Panel,
    stat_axis=2,
)


def panel4d_init(self, data=None, axis1=None, axis2=None, axis3=None,
                 axis4=None, copy=False, dtype=None):

    self._init_data(data=data, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2,
                    axis3=axis3, axis4=axis4,
                    copy=copy, dtype=dtype)

Panel4D.__init__ = panel4d_init
```

It is just a [part of the Pandas source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/panel4d.py)  but slightly reworked.

Then you get

```
>>> Panel4D(np.random.rand(4,4,4,4))
Out[1]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panelnd.Panel4D'>
Dimensions: 4 (axis1) x 4 (axis2) x 4 (axis3) x 4 (axis4)
Axis1 axis: 0 to 3
Axis2 axis: 0 to 3
Axis3 axis: 0 to 3
Axis4 axis: 0 to 3
```

and in contrary to the answer given in [pandas access axis by user-defined name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533093/pandas-access-axis-by-user-defined-name), an instance of `Panel4D` then is fully functional and behaves just like an instance of `pandas.Panel4D`. For example you now can do `Panel4D(np.empty((1,1,1,1)))[0]` whithout haveing an Exception thrown.

Comment: good you answered, I could not mark it as duplicate since the former question was not accepted.